# Android Bending View canvas to give curl effect

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

Can anyone help in bending view to achieve following effect. I am using custom view group and i want to manipulate the Canvas to achieve following effect, can anyone help me please.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to know:
   [Camera](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html)
   [Matrix](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html)

And here is a great project:
https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker ,which implement the effect you want.